# Using numeric generics to get min/max of native numeric types, Int32.MaxValue doesn't appear to exist

Tags: generics, f#

I was in need of a numeric-generic function that could access the numeric type's `MinValue` and `MaxValue`. Since all BCL types have these members, I thought I could get away with writing something like this:

```
let inline zeroOrMax(x: ^a) =
    match x with
    | a when a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero -> x
    | a when a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne -> 
        let maxVal = (^a: (static member MaxValue : ^a) ())  
        maxVal 
    | a when -a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne -> 
        let maxVal = (^a: (static member MaxValue : ^a) ())  
        -maxVal 
    | _ -> ...
```

This function would give you either zero or the (negative/positive) max value of the underlying type.

This works find when I create my own type that implements `MaxValue`, but while `Int32`, `Int64` etc have static members `MaxValue` and `MinValue`, I keep getting static compile errors that the parameter does not have said static member:

```
let test (x: int64) =
    // error FS0001: The type 'int64' does not support the operator 'get_MaxValue'
    zeroOrMax x
```

I would assume this is because F# treats these type specially. Or perhaps I simply need a different syntax. Is there a way around this while keeping numeric genericity *and* accessing the Min/Max values of the underlying types?

Comment: `int64.MaxValue` is a _member constant_, not a _property_.

Comment: @fyodor ouch, dejavu, feels like I saw that earlier. Guess there's no trivial workaround than?

Comment: No, there's no way. I created a [generic function](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/615f86cbce90596740efdc717cb863a57cefeee4/FsControl.Core/Operators.fs#L397) in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) that does this by [overloading many different types](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/615f86cbce90596740efdc717cb863a57cefeee4/FsControl.Core/Numeric.fs#L476). You can use it or copy the code there.

Comment: @Gustavo, interesting approach. I was thinking along those lines (I hoped to ducktype some things together, guess that won't happen yet). One other way of cheating the system led to strange (or not?) behavior of F#, [reported here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1951).

Comment: Interesting bug report, as always. I will add some code from that generic function as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are not taken into account for statically resolved type member constraints.

As stated in the comments, you can use create a generic function like [maxValue](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/615f86cbce90596740efdc717cb863a57cefeee4/FsControl.Core/Operators.fs#L397) from [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) which does what you want by specifying overloads for each known type.

Here's a 'standalone' version of [this fragment of code](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/615f86cbce90596740efdc717cb863a57cefeee4/FsControl.Core/Numeric.fs#L476):

```
open System

type MaxValue = MaxValue with
    static member ($) (_:unit          , _:MaxValue) = ()
    static member ($) (_:bool          , _:MaxValue) = true
    static member ($) (_:char          , _:MaxValue) = Char.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:byte          , _:MaxValue) = Byte.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:sbyte         , _:MaxValue) = SByte.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:float         , _:MaxValue) = Double.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:int16         , _:MaxValue) = Int16.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:int           , _:MaxValue) = Int32.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:int64         , _:MaxValue) = Int64.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:float32       , _:MaxValue) = Single.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:uint16        , _:MaxValue) = UInt16.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:uint32        , _:MaxValue) = UInt32.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:uint64        , _:MaxValue) = UInt64.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:decimal       , _:MaxValue) = Decimal.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:DateTime      , _:MaxValue) = DateTime.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:DateTimeOffset, _:MaxValue) = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue
    static member ($) (_:TimeSpan      , _:MaxValue) = TimeSpan.MaxValue

let inline maxValue() :'r =  Unchecked.defaultof<'r> $ MaxValue

type MaxValue with
    static member inline ($) ((_:'a*'b         ), _:MaxValue) = maxValue(), maxValue()
    static member inline ($) ((_:'a*'b*'c      ), _:MaxValue) = maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue()
    static member inline ($) ((_:'a*'b*'c*'d   ), _:MaxValue) = maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue()
    static member inline ($) ((_:'a*'b*'c*'d*'e), _:MaxValue) = maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue(), maxValue()

// Usage
let x:int  = maxValue()
// val x : int = 2147483647

let y:int * float *TimeSpan = maxValue()
// val y : int * float * TimeSpan = (2147483647, 1.797693135e+308, 10675199.02:48:05.4775807)
```